# How to add background image in thymeleaf index page

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I've created index page using html + css in VSC and it works fine. Then I want to copy this to my thymeleaf project to use it. Some problems occure during loading background image.

I searched then i can upload image throught **th:style** like this:

```
<body th:style="'background: url(images/weatherBackground.jpg)'">
```

but how can i add properties like:

```
height: 100%;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

or if it possible to have separate css file (who have url to image and properties) ?

Previously i have connected css file (with url image) to index page, and styles was added to page but not a background image. I've checked all roots to files are ok.

```
<link href="css/index.css" th:href="@{/css/index.css}" rel='stylesheet' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try this way.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
// HTML Content
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-image :  url(images/weatherBackground.jpg);
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: All of those background-* rules can combined into `background: url(images/weatherBackground.jpg) center/cover no-repeat`